# Full downgrade from 14.04.3 lts-vivid stack to standard 14.04 lts stack

Tags: 14.04, kernel, graphics, downgrade

the issue is well represented by the title. How can I completely revert the 14.04.3 lts-vivid stack (3.19 kernel + updated graphics stack) to the standard 14.04.0/1 trusty stack? I know that the most staightforward way should be a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04.0 or 14.04.1, but I have many applications which I would like to keep instead of reinstalling all the stuff from scratch.

Comment: As I suspect there seem to be no web documentation on this matter. Any advice about that?